# Extend attribute="value" selector in Less

Tags: html, css, less

I'm using semantic and trying to extend their grid to accommodate built in CMS functions. Usually, this is just a simple matter of using &:extend(*classname* all). However Semantic has some unique ways of coding that has made this very difficult.

I'm trying to find a way to extend only one value in the following:

```
.ui-grid > .row > [class*="thirteen wide"].column {width: @thirteenWide !important}
```

I need to extend on the *thirteen* only and not the remainder of the selection. A simple *&extent(thirteen all)* does not work in this case because *thirteen* is not declared anywhere but is only used to create this specific selector.

Comment: What does this have to do with C preprocessors?

Comment: It doesn't, that was a mistake. It should have been css preprocessors. I edited the post to include to correct preprocessor.

Comment: Let's ensure you're understanding what `extend` actually does. I.e. `extend` adds your selector to a ruleset you point to in parens... Now how are you going to extend something that does not even exist? (Terminology here may be quite confusing so it would be helpful if you give an example of the  resulting CSS you'd like to get by "extending on the thirteen only").

Comment: Or do you mean something like [this](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.ui-grid%20%3E%20.row%20%3E%20%5Bclass*%3D%5C%22thirteen%20wide%5C%22%5D.column%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%5Ctwidth%3A%20foo%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Bclass*%3D%5C%22YOUR-ID%20wide%5C%22%5D%3Aextend(%5Bclass*%3D%5C%22thirteen%20wide%5C%22%5D%20all)%20%7B%7D%22%7D)?

Comment: @seven-phases-max Yes, this exactly along the lines of what I was looking for. It's unfortunate that we can't select the _thirteen_ itself. I was hoping for a more robust solution where I could extend on _thirteen_ have it apply not only to the selector above but any other attribute selector that contains _thirteen_. I figured this was most likely wishful thinking.    Please post this as a solution so that I can give you credit.

Comment: Also, I know that it sounds odd that I want to extend a thing that does not exist. The semantic grid numbering system works off a combination of classes to produce the grid element. In this sense, the numbered class does nothing by itself but when used in combination with at least one other grid class it becomes meaningful. It's an unusual approach to a grid system but is also the way they been able to correctly apply flexbox to their grid system where other attempts are relatively half-assed in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I get it. It makes sense since the `class` attr selector is definitely related to what `extend` is aimed for, but yes, I doubt Less will ever support something like this since it's just a one specific of all that attr selector types (they are just too many, too specific, and too evolving for the Less's minimalistic approach). So it's more about the library design (i.e. reusable things should be made explicitly reusable) rather than the language design (actually *all* `extend all` use-cases are like this since a "CSS theme/framework lib" != "CSS building blocks lib").

Comment: So making an answer to not leave it unanswered...

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, `extend` can't target specific items/entities *inside* an attribute selector. `Extend` always treats any attribute selector as an integral element (i.e. as a whole) w/o even trying to understand what it's supposed to mean. So the best thing you can do in this case is something like:

```less
.ui-grid > .row > [class*="thirteen wide"].column {
    width: foo;
}

[class*="my-id wide"]:extend([class*="thirteen wide"] all) {}
// or:
.my-id:extend([class*="thirteen wide"] all) {}
// etc.
```

[Demo.](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.ui-grid%20%3E%20.row%20%3E%20%5Bclass*%3D%5C%22thirteen%20wide%5C%22%5D.column%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%5Ctwidth%3A%20foo%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%5Bclass*%3D%5C%22YOUR-ID%20wide%5C%22%5D%3Aextend(%5Bclass*%3D%5C%22thirteen%20wide%5C%22%5D%20all)%20%7B%7D%22%7D)